# React : Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this syntax error, but have no idea where the end sequence is failing:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
        <h1>Look at this!</h1>
        <h2>This is MAGIC!</h2>
        <a href="https://www.mozilla.com/"> 
        <p>Think about all this power of <code>React</code></p>
      <textarea />
                </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What syntax error?  Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two unterminated JSX contents in your code. One for the first `textarea` and one for the `a`. Here is the fixed code. By the way, I agree with the linter suggestion.

```js
  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <textarea rows="4" cols="50" />
          <h1>Look at this!</h1>
          <h2>This is MAGIC!</h2>
          <a href="https://www.mozilla.com/">Go to Mozilla</a>
          <p>
            Think about all this power of <code>React</code>
          </p>
          <textarea />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<a>` element is not closed. I suggest you to add linters it will be easier for you to spot these errors, also it's strange why you editor didn't point that.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How is not closed?

Answer (score 0):

html `<a>` tag needs to be closed using `</a>` if there is any content like text, div, etc.

```
  <a href="https://www.mozilla.com/">Go to Mozilla</a>
```